# DHCPDISCOVER requests from off-by-one MAC addresses

Tags: networking, centos7, dhcp

Recently I was doing some wireshark capture and tcpdump in an isolated local network. I noticed unusual dhcp traffic from mac addresses that are 1 off from existing mac address of network interfaces

[wireshark capture of dhcp traffic from machine 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vqbH.png)

[wireshark capture of dhcp traffic from machine 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwpap.png)

[machine 1 mac addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExeXr.png)

[machine 2 mac addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSspD.png)

I searched for solutions such as [how to stop dhcp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426868/how-does-dhcpd-stop-on-centos) and [dhcpdiscover off by 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/242570/dhcpdiscover-requests-from-an-off-by-one-mac-address) and verified

1. `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` doesn't exist
2. `dhcpd` and `dhclient` are not running
3. There is no explicit IPMI setting in BIOS. I'm not sure if it's phrased differently in my case.
4. `lshw` tool is not available on the machines. `lspci` and `dmidecode` do not show any hidden network interfaces
5. `lsmod` shows `ipmi_ssif` and `ipmi_devintf` and `ipmi_msghandler`

It is strongly discouraged to install any third-party software on the two machines for security reasons, so I have to make use of only what's available. What is the cause of such DHCP traffic and how should I go about disabling them?

Comment: What is the environment? Computer type, make, model?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen The OS is Centos 7

Comment: Could you provide the asked details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive search online, I found this https://wiki.wireshark.org/SLL and I quote

> When capturing from the "any" device, or from one of those other devices, in Linux, the libpcap doesn't supply the link-layer header for the real "hardware protocol" like Ethernet, but instead supplies a fake link-layer header for this pseudo-protocol.

Because I was using `any` as interface in `tcpdump`, it was likely that the off-by-1 mac addresses were fake ones added by *libpcap*. I verified my hypothesis by doing some capture on individual interfaces, which in turn didn't catch any traffic with unknown mac addresses.